# System V msgrcv blocking in thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals, message-queue

I have an application which has signal handler and created a thread to handle message queue.
Below is signal Handler,

```
   /*! \Register handle on SIGINT. */
   signal(SIGINT, CloseHandler);

VOID CloseHandler(INT32 sig)
{
if(sig == SIGINT)
gAppExitFlag = 1;
return;
}
```

I have created a joinable thread to receive message queue,

```
      /* Initialize and set thread detached attribute */
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
  if(0 != (count = pthread_create(&ModemDetectionHandel, &attr, &ModemDetectionOperation, (void *)&gAppContext)))
  {
     DS3_ERROR(DS3_TELEMETRY_APP, "Error in creating thread ModemDetectionOperation");
  }
```

In thread, I have created a message queue and call msgrcv with msgflg 0.
So it will block until any message receive.
Now when I send SIGINT to process but msgrcv don't come back and thread block in msgrcv.

My application get stuck in joining thread.

As per msgrcv man page "       * The  calling process catches a signal.  In this case the system call fails with errno set to EINTR.  (msgrcv() is never automatically restarted after being interrupted by
         a signal handler, regardless of the setting of the SA_RESTART flag when establishing a signal handler.)"

Why thread/msgrcv don't get signal?
If I make thread as a main loop then it comes back and application exit successfully.

Comment: How do you send the `SIGINT` signals? Have you changed any signal masks?

Comment: No, I haven't change signal mask

Comment: What about the `SIGINT` signal? How do you generate it?

Comment: Just execute command kill -2 <process-id>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a signal is sent to a *process*, one thread which has not blocked it will handle it, but it is unspecified which thread this will be.  You said that you have not blocked `SIGINT` on all the other threads.  So the most likely explanation for the behavior you see is that the signal is handled by the main thread, and not the thread which calls `msgrcv`.

To fix this, you could block `SIGINT` on all threads except the thread that calls `msgrcv`.  This will ensure that the signal is handled by that thread.

If you have multiple threads which need to be interrupted, this won't work.  In this case, you will probably need to block `SIGINT` for all threads, and use `sigwait` in a special interrupt-handling thread to receive the `SIGINT` signal.  This thread then can send another signal (perhaps `SIGUSR1`) to all threads which need to be interrupted, with one `pthread_kill` for each such thread.  Or maybe you can use `pthread_cancel` as well, depending on what your needs are.

Comment: Then I also can call pthread_kill before joining thread. Actually I have multi threaded application about 11-12 threads.

Comment: Sure, if that works for you, but I don't think it's straightforward to handle the case where the thread exits early.

Comment: Florian, In my application, other thread is using SIGALRM. And with this msgrcv gives EINTR error. Any solution for this? Can I set thread to receive only specific signal only with pthread_sigmask?

Comment: Yes, you can block `SIGALRM` with `pthread_sigmask`. But the thread will no longer be able to use `sleep`, you'll have to use the `nanosleep` or `usleep` functions instead.

Comment: Example for what? Maybe it's time to post a new question.